# Xamarin Auth with Mvvmcross & Cross Platform API Client

Tags: android, ios, authentication, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm looking at using Mvvmcross and the Xamarin Auth component to authenticate against my own OAuth 2.0 API which uses DotNetOpenAuth.  I'll be using the users username and password to exchange for tokens.

I have created an IAPIClientService in a core portable library meaning this cannot contain any Xamarin.Auth code or classes as you cannot use components in portable libraries (AFAIK).  So the logic to authenicate is going to have to go in the views layer in the Android and iOS applications.

Also I'm having trouble working out how my API client in the portable library would work as I wouldn't be able to make requests using the `OAuth2Request` from the Auth component I would have to use HttpClient and manually add the tokens to the IAPIClientService requests.

Has anyone dealt with this scenario?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a case where this DOESNT belong in the PCL but is a shared class that is linked to from each project (iOS/Android)?

Comment: Take a look at Cheesebaron's implementation here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.

This includes the code for connecting to ACS to swap credentials for a token. Not exactly the same as what you are doing, but should help get you a long way there.

Comment: Whoa that's a bit much for an Mvx noob ...